# Apply change on every release

Tags: git

I've currently got an app that communicates with a webserver. Of this webserver, I've got 2 instances. A testing one on my local machine, and a production one on a remote machine. Say IP `192.168.0.100` for my local machine, and `http://mycompany.com/webapi` for the remote one.

I'm using Git flow as described in [image: this webpage]
(see http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Now as soon as I create a release branch, I want to switch from my local server to the remote server.

The IP is stored in a public final static variable. That means that re-applying one commit which changes it from my local IP to the remote url would work.

What would be the right way to go about this? I had creating a stash and applying it at every release in mind, but to someone lazy like me that seems like too much manual labor, and too much chance for things to go wrong (like forgetting to apply the stash)

Answer (score 1):

That IP address is configuration, not code, so it shouldn't be hard-coded in your application.

One common approach, as popularized by [The 12-Factor App](http://12factor.net/config) and [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), is to set the IP address using an environment variable:

> An app’s *config* is everything that is likely to vary between [deploys](http://12factor.net/codebase) (staging, production, developer environments, etc). This includes:
>
> - Resource handles to the database, Memcached, and other [backing services](http://12factor.net/backing-services)
> - Credentials to external services such as Amazon S3 or Twitter
> - Per-deploy values such as the canonical hostname for the deploy
>
> Apps sometimes store config as constants in the code. This is a violation of twelve-factor, which requires **strict separation of config from code**. Config varies substantially across deploys, code does not.
>
> …
>
> **The twelve-factor app stores config in *environment variables*** (often shortened to *env vars* or *env*). Env vars are easy to change between deploys without changing any code; unlike config files, there is little chance of them being checked into the code repo accidentally; and unlike custom config files, or other config mechanisms such as Java System Properties, they are a language- and OS-agnostic standard.

Another common approach (that 12-Factor explicitly rejects) is to version a sample configuration file like `config.ini.sample` but require users to copy this to an unversioned and `.gitignore`d file like `config.ini` that is actually used by the application. This lets you change settings per-install by modifying a file that Git doesn't care about.

It is difficult to give you a more specific answer without information about the language and stack you're using. Some frameworks, for example, have this idea baked in.